# too many connections.#1040 Can't connect to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been running a web application. When I try to login to the phpmyadmin, it denied access and shown "too many connections" and none of the application which uses database is working now :( . I google and increased the max_connection to 250. Still I cant get into mysql server nor myapplications are working.

I haven't used `mysql_close();` whenever I make a db connection. Is that the cause of this problem? What is the solution?

Comment: you have shell access to mysql? if so login to it and run show processlist
and you can kill the ones you dont need from there

Comment: but there s only 1 process in it

Comment: your code might be making too many connections to the db, ex: if a link is already existing to mysql you should use that than making a new link or too many users connecting at once,
PS: check whether ur connections are persistent or not as well

Comment: If I remember right `too many connections` is not only thrown when to many parallel connections are active, but also when the maximum number of connections per user or per hour is reached.

Comment: As said in other comments, you do not need to close the connections, they will be closed automatically at the end of the script. However, if you have scripts that for some reason don't finish all the way, for example stuck in a loop or waiting for other script, the connection will stay open. Users will probably refresh the page and more connections will be left open. You should track down the script that is causing this. A simple restart of the MySQL server should reset the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Kill all processes created by your web app through task manager(if youre Win user) or command line(for Linux).Then you should be able to get to mysql server. And yes you should close all your opened connection through code

Comment: Quote from the PHP documentation: `Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.`

Comment: But there is only one process shown in process list

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes  this is true. But when application havent closed "naturally" connections remain opened. So maybe this happened after some error

Comment: does restarting mysql server erases data in database?

Comment: No it does not mysql server is just client application database data are sotored on hard drive thats why they are called persistent. So when you close application turn off PC etc. they remain "saved"

Comment: You may also have to do some performance tuning. First identify where the open connections come from (i.e. Do you really have 250 simultaneous users of the web application? If not, is each page visit leaving a connection open? Does your application use persistent connections?) then work to either decrease the number of connections or increase your MySQL server's resource limits accordingly.